# Redirect http to https via IIS

Tags: iis, https, url-rewriting, http-redirect

I have this application that I just installed a `SSL` certificate for. Yest I tried to redirect the users to use only the `HTTPS://url.com`. and prevent them from using the `http://url.com site`. However because I lack understanding the regular expressions to define the Pattern and the condition and unfortunately, I could not find a guide with some example of how to define those rules. I would like a concrete example of how to set this up `https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure you have the URL Rewrite feature added. In IIS manager configure the following in the URL rewrite section.

1. Create inbound rule (Blank Rule)
2. Requested URL : `Matches the pattern`
3. Using: `Wildcards`
4. Pattern: `*`

**Conditions**

- Input: `{HTTPS}`
- Type: `Matches the pattern`
- Pattern: `off`

**Action**

- Action Type: `Redirect`
- Redirect URL: `https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}`
- Append Query String `Checked`
- Redirect type: `Found (302)`

**Once you have done this. Create a condition.**

1. Right click your new rule
2. Conditions -> Add+
3. Condition Input : `{QUERY_STRING}`
4. `Matches the Pattern`
5. Pattern: `off`

Essentially it should look like this:

[image: Redirect Rule]

All traffic using a http request will be automatically redirected to the https port.

Comment: What do you mean by {HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI} it should be replaced with the actual rules that matches my url, right?

Comment: I have amended my answer which should hopefully clarify the points. No, you do not replace those with your site. All settings are as is displayed.

Comment: Does it work on phones too? For me on phone any http url will just load forever. But https urls instantly work. Any idea how to fix this? On pc http will just be redirected correctly.

Comment: To me also works on phones. Try another browser and/or try incognito browsing to see if works.

Answer (score 5):

I think I've found a solution without url rewrite. In IIS, right click on the website, choose "Manage web site - Advanced settings", expand "Behaviour", expand "HSTS" and set to "True" the properties "Enabled" and "RedirectHttpToHttps".

Update:
As @jonasfh pointed out, you need anyway to have bindings both to http and https, because only the successful requests to http are redirected to https. So, if the request to http isn't successful (because http binding is not present) the redirect to https doesn't happen. Thank you.

Update2: just wanted to add that after the settings a site restart from IIS is needed.

Comment: Seems that for this to work, you need to have bindings both to http and https

Comment: Yes, because the successful requests to http are redirected to https, if the request to http isn't successful (because http binding is not present) the redirect to https doesn't happen.

Comment: Just thought you might want to update your answer :)

Comment: Does it work on phones too for you guys? For me on phone any http url will just load forever. But https urls instantly work. Any idea how to fix this? On pc http will just be redirected correctly.

Answer (score 1):

My method from Global.asax

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
        {
#if !DEBUG
            if (!Context.Request.IsSecureConnection)
            {
                if (Context.Request.Url.ToString().Contains(".well-known")) return;

                Response.StatusCode = 301;

                Response.RedirectPermanent(Context.Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", "https:"));
            }
#endif
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I followed.

go to the publish folder and open the Web.config file and paste the following rewrite rules within <system.webServer> tags

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

- Make sure that the 'Require SSL' option is unchecked in the SSL settings of the related site on IIS.

[image]